# cakephp find associated models of associated model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am calling a find on a model called Book which is associated with a model Page(book_id)

However Page is associated with a model called Asset(page_id). I would like to get the array with all three models

```
Book
    Page1
        Asset1
        Asset2
        Asset3
    Page2
        Asset1
        Asset2
        Asset3
```

The code I have at the moment only get me Book and Page

```
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array('Book.' . $this->Book->primaryKey => $id),
    'contain' => 'Page'
);
$books = $this->Book->find('first', $options);
```

Book hasMany Pages
Page hasMany Assets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can contain deeper associations, like it says in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations)

Example from the docs

```
$this->User->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Profile',
        'Account' => array(
            'AccountSummary'
        ),
        'Post' => array(
            'PostAttachment' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'name'),
                'PostAttachmentHistory' => array(
                    'HistoryNotes' => array(
                        'fields' => array('id', 'note')
                    )
                )
            ),
            'Tag' => array(
                'conditions' => array('Tag.name LIKE' => '%happy%')
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Same thing with your models...

```
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array('Book.' . $this->Book->primaryKey => $id),
    'contain' => array('Page' => array('Asset')))
);
$books = $this->Book->find('first', $options);
```

Should work if your associations are set correctly (and if all models implement containable behavior).

**EDIT**
(to address the confusion the OP had)

The nested contain options works for the model expanding the array. For example, if models are associated like this

```
Model-A -> Model-B -> Model-C & Model-D
        -> Model-E -> Model-C
```

you could get the entire array with data like

```
Model-A
  Model-B1
    Model-C1
    Model-C2
    Model-D2
  Model-B2
    Model-C (null)
    Model-D3
  Model-E1
    Model-C1
    Model-C3
```

using something like

```
$this->ModelA->find('all'), array(
       'contain' => array(
          'Model-B' => array('Model-C', 'Model-D'),
          'Model-E' => array('Model-C')
       )
);
```

Also, you can [add options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containablebehavior-options) to the containable array, including the ones used for searching, like `'conditions'` (though be careful with this, it means that if the model doesn't match the condition it will return a null array, it does *not* mean the the whole "Model-A" will not be in the returned data since one of the nested conditions was not fulfilled).

Comment: thanks, I misunderstood the doc when I read it. I thought asset had to be associated with Book for this to work. The result is perfect now.